# Angular 8 - Populating elements in child component dynamically at runtime by passing data from parent component

Tags: json, angular8

I have a json which is getting passed as @Input() to a child component. The child component renders elements depending upon the values in JSON. I need to pass more values to the json later, (data fetched at runtime as per user selection). Or somehow use those dynamic values to populate elements in child component.
How can I achieve that?
It's a nested Json with arrays and objects, and so I can't use the [(ngModel)] directly to correspond to the value in JSON.
ngOnChanges() is not getting fired once the @Input() receives it's value for the first time.

Is there any other way to get the main issue to work?

Answer (score 1):

```
Input() object : any ; //Supposing your nested JSON coming in object
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes && changes.object ) {
      this.pc1IDInput = changes.object.currentValue;
     //Call relevant method here 
      this.relevantMethod();
    }
  }
```